# Can antidepressants actually limit your ability temporarily to feel happiness or excitement?

Tags: antidepressants

For example, suppose a psychiatrist prescribes his/her patient a mood stabilizer that doesn't allow their mood to deviate a lot, either positively or negatively.

Lets assume that over the course of time, the patient gets better. But does that also mean, that the medicine has limited the patient's ability to feel extremely positive moods too? In the sense that, if the patient comes off of the medicine in some time, and he comes across experiences that will positively impact his mood; does that mean that the patient would have felt better with those experiences if he had been off the medicine, compared to if he would've still continued with the meds?

Comment: Your title was a valid question, but the actual text is off topic for the reason given in the close notice.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have edited the question. Can this now be kept open?

Comment: If this question were on topic in the first place, it would have belonged in Psychology & Neuroscience and would have been migrated there. So if it gets reopened, that's what will happen. Wouldn't it be simpler to just ask the question there?